# Older versions of spaCy throws "KeyError: 'package'" error when trying to install a model

Tags: python, nlp, keyerror, spacy

I use spaCy 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64 with  python3.5. To install the English model of spaCy, I tried to run:

This gives me the error message:

```
ubun@ner-3:~/NeuroNER-master/src$  python3.5 -m spacy.en.download
Downloading parsing model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plac_core.py", line 328, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 18, in main
    download('en', force=False, data_path=data_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/download.py", line 25, in download
    about.__models__.get(lang, lang), data_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/__init__.py", line 159, in package
    pool = Pool(app_name, app_version, expand_path(data_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/pool.py", line 19, in __init__
    super(Pool, self).__init__(app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 51, in load
    for package in self.packages():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 47, in packages
    yield self.__class__.package_class(path=os.path.join(self.path, path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sputnik/package.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])
KeyError: 'package'
ubun@ner-3:~/NeuroNER-master/src$
```

What could the issue be?

The output of `pip3 freeze` is:

```
ubun@ner-3:~/NeuroNER-master/src$ pip3 freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
cloudpickle==0.2.2
command-not-found==0.3
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==1.31.2
cytoolz==0.8.2
decorator==4.0.11
dill==0.2.6
en-core-web-sm==1.2.0
flexmock==0.10.2
language-selector==0.1
matplotlib==2.0.0
murmurhash==0.26.4
networkx==1.11
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pathlib==1.0.1
plac==0.9.6
preshed==0.46.4
protobuf==3.2.0
pycurl==7.19.3
pygobject==3.12.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-apt===0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2016.10
requests==2.13.0
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.0
semver==2.7.6
six==1.10.0
spacy==1.6.0
sputnik==0.9.3
tensorflow==1.0.1
termcolor==1.1.0
thinc==6.2.0
toolz==0.8.2
tqdm==4.11.2
ufw===0.34-rc-0ubuntu2
ujson==1.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
wrapt==1.10.10
yolk==0.4.3
```

I have the same issue with spaCy 1.5.0. The issue isn't present with spacy-1.7.2.

Comment: 1.6 also has same problem. i went to 1.7.2 to bypass error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

That's because the `sputnik` package has been deprecated since spacy > 1.5.

Best bet is to upgrade your Spacy to the latest one. Or at least up till 1.7 =)

---

Otherwise, you could try:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/download/v1.6.0/en-1.1.0.tar.gz
```

But do note that this might mess up your python environment if have the new spacy models already installed. **Remember to use virtual environment, esp. on back-versioned libraries!**

Also, this is dependent on the fact that Spacy 1.6 can be installed properly =(

---

## In Short

See https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/711 and https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v1.6.0

---

## In Long

Looking at the code from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sputnik

From `sputnik/package.py`:

```
import os
import logging

from . import util
from . import default
from .package_stub import PackageStub


class NotIncludedException(Exception): pass


class Package(PackageStub):  # installed package
    def __init__(self, path):
        meta = util.json_load(os.path.join(path, default.META_FILENAME))
        super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.meta = meta
        self.path = path

    @property
    def manifest(self):
        return self.meta['manifest']

    def has_file(self, *path_parts):
        return any(m for m in self.manifest if tuple(m['path']) == path_parts)

    def file_path(self, *path_parts):
        path = util.get_path(*path_parts)

        if not self.has_file(*path_parts):
            raise NotIncludedException('package does not include file: %s' % path)

        return os.path.join(self.path, path)

    def dir_path(self, *path_parts):
        # TODO check whether path is part of package
        path = util.get_path(*path_parts)
        return os.path.join(self.path, path)
```

Looking at

```
from . import default
meta = util.json_load(os.path.join(path, default.META_FILENAME))
super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])
```

We see that `meta['package']` pointing to `sputnik/default.py`, i.e.

```
# cli/param defaults
find_package_string = ''
find_meta = False
find_cache = False
search_string = ''
build_package_path = '.'
repository_url = 'https://index.spacy.io'
purge_cache = False
purge_pool = False

# misc
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 16
ARCHIVE_FILENAME = 'archive.gz'
META_FILENAME = 'meta.json'
COMPRESSLEVEL = 9
COOKIES_FILENAME = 'cookies.txt'
CACHE_DIRNAME = '__cache__'
```

That is pointing to `META_FILENAME`, i.e. the `meta.json`, which is refering to the json from https://index.spacy.io/

```
{
  "de-1.0.0": [
    "/models/de-1.0.0/meta.json", 
    "707615c7822e5fdba0c9047d7c864f48"
  ], 
  "en-1.1.0": [
    "/models/en-1.1.0/meta.json", 
    "7d928b8171ece380c29285d8e1bf7879"
  ], 
  "en_glove_cc_300_1m_vectors-1.0.0": [
    "/models/en_glove_cc_300_1m_vectors-1.0.0/meta.json", 
    "390182610e60ada31bd1d78408b86ada"
  ]
}
```

And if we follow the breadcrumbs to https://index.spacy.io/models/en-1.1.0/meta.json , we see

```
{
  "archive": [
    "archive.gz",
    "84cc5c9869bfdc09072bb8d217d30c53"
  ],
  "etag": "cd1ba4eed97115f409caf42209b503f3",
  "manifest": [
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "6d0d4b6ab1c63bae1f643d74be45b58a"
      ],
      "noffset": 81,
      "path": [
        "tokenizer",
        "prefix.txt"
      ],
      "size": 58
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "0653ca64d24e3772ca226c0043a54d28"
      ],
      "noffset": 203,
      "path": [
        "tokenizer",
        "suffix.txt"
      ],
      "size": 121
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "b0e952a69870469e2c24a06a63b7b8b3"
      ],
      "noffset": 4766,
      "path": [
        "tokenizer",
        "specials.json"
      ],
      "size": 57389
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "f19ca88b84e10c13ce184587f23b291d"
      ],
      "noffset": 4852,
      "path": [
        "tokenizer",
        "infix.txt"
      ],
      "size": 132
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "43260460e916738695dca5ea58c25634"
      ],
      "noffset": 5466,
      "path": [
        "tokenizer",
        "morphs.json"
      ],
      "size": 5456
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "011a72e32df2c3c87817721c903cbb33"
      ],
      "noffset": 6023,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "gazetteer.json"
      ],
      "size": 2744
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "a5be0ac5dc3d9e07e5af33db25f2df1c"
      ],
      "noffset": 31023404,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "lexemes.bin"
      ],
      "size": 83042240
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "aef38bcb805c2ed4edf17ab9b208369e"
      ],
      "noffset": 31024046,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "tag_map.json"
      ],
      "size": 2557
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "39728b8675762177066dd16162baaf5c"
      ],
      "noffset": 31024084,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "oov_prob"
      ],
      "size": 10
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "a336ae975fbe608c72b5727610445c2e"
      ],
      "noffset": 226419131,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "vec.bin"
      ],
      "size": 211519189
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "24a5c128601ffc987b8aff10c8f8acff"
      ],
      "noffset": 226419335,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "lemma_rules.json"
      ],
      "size": 633
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "b0f18c32ef9d83b8214db66f516900b2"
      ],
      "noffset": 235404066,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "strings.json"
      ],
      "size": 18811305
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "5ead864c56cce491889180b161ae43a6"
      ],
      "noffset": 235452331,
      "path": [
        "vocab",
        "serializer.json"
      ],
      "size": 190524
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "cc7c42f987cb1c38ec80f5fb1e7f2e93"
      ],
      "noffset": 243140134,
      "path": [
        "pos",
        "model"
      ],
      "size": 11799888
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "00613ddd9d320b7a26cef788919cae7e"
      ],
      "noffset": 266495675,
      "path": [
        "ner",
        "model"
      ],
      "size": 36553844
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "5e6e9afbd65d1d13b9b6b3bb709694e0"
      ],
      "noffset": 266495905,
      "path": [
        "ner",
        "config.json"
      ],
      "size": 1237
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "f37b1a7e8ccaddb5a36d093ae6511052"
      ],
      "noffset": 556251621,
      "path": [
        "deps",
        "model"
      ],
      "size": 444221600
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "d4a5246448e378f1f211fd93bfa4d344"
      ],
      "noffset": 556251964,
      "path": [
        "deps",
        "config.json"
      ],
      "size": 1450
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "bb55705666a12253d15e332329e2b1f0"
      ],
      "noffset": 556490251,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "index.adj"
      ],
      "size": 824127
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "f6e4bd2b3473a5e40a749719c2268846"
      ],
      "noffset": 556508918,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "sentidx.vrb"
      ],
      "size": 73166
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "ef3e1c35234edb8d7394c75f4b344c70"
      ],
      "noffset": 556514986,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "adj.exc"
      ],
      "size": 23019
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "191515ffba85d4461d37f93059de2840"
      ],
      "noffset": 556516925,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "sents.vrb"
      ],
      "size": 5319
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "fa5c7d42ec3214777011eabd13f34bc9"
      ],
      "noffset": 556517242,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "frames.vrb"
      ],
      "size": 1125
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "8c949e6ef352295997b09e2446364e43"
      ],
      "noffset": 557891009,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "index.noun"
      ],
      "size": 4786655
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "fa5c7d42ec3214777011eabd13f34bc9"
      ],
      "noffset": 557891326,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "verb.Framestext"
      ],
      "size": 1125
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "98636a3c14d26002264d352ea57d713a"
      ],
      "noffset": 558062212,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "index.verb"
      ],
      "size": 523980
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "951700d36c2c84a20fda9550028dc7cc"
      ],
      "noffset": 558075491,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "noun.exc"
      ],
      "size": 38301
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "d8016b74fcb68ef5139a4c51d22bdbdf"
      ],
      "noffset": 558086414,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "verb.exc"
      ],
      "size": 38033
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "a55bf29bc2f59e33ea31568874f6a294"
      ],
      "noffset": 558132762,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "index.adv"
      ],
      "size": 162816
    },
    {
      "checksum": [
        "md5",
        "c0d9112ae92a3ce3a149541c16c0386a"
      ],
      "noffset": 558132844,
      "path": [
        "wordnet",
        "adv.exc"
      ],
      "size": 85
    }
  ],
  "package": {
    "compatibility": {
      "spacy": null
    },
    "description": "default English model",
    "license": "public domain",
    "name": "en",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

And the end of trail leads to https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/711