# Error while loading english module in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, on jupyter notebook.
I just installed the latest version of spaCy using the following because my english module wasn't downloading

```
 conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.0.11
```

However while installing spaCy using the above command it said:
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   anaconda:        5.2.0-py36_3

While loading the english module via :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

I get the following:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-76abff010c5f> in <module>()
----> 1 nlp = spacy.load('en')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, vocab, tokenizer, parser, tagger, entity, matcher, serializer, vectors, via)
     13     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     14         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 15     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     16 
     17 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py in get_package_by_name(name, via)
     42     """Import and load a Language class.
     43 
---> 44     lang (unicode): Two-letter language code, e.g. 'en'.
     45     RETURNS (Language): Language class.
     46     """

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/__init__.py in package(app_name, app_version, package_string, data_path)
    157         data_path = default_data_path(app_name)
    158 
--> 159     pool = Pool(app_name, app_version, expand_path(data_path))
    160     return pool.get(package_string)
    161 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/pool.py in __init__(self, app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
     17 
     18     def __init__(self, app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs):
---> 19         super(Pool, self).__init__(app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
     20         self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
     21         self.cleanup()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py in __init__(self, app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
     31             raise InvalidDataPathException(self.data_path)
     32 
---> 33         self.load()
     34 
     35     def packages(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py in load(self)
     49     def load(self):
     50         self._packages = {}
---> 51         for package in self.packages():
     52             self._packages[package.ident] = package
     53 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py in packages(self)
     45                 continue
     46 
---> 47             yield self.__class__.package_class(path=os.path.join(self.path, path))
     48 
     49     def load(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package.py in __init__(self, path)
     13     def __init__(self, path):
     14         meta = util.json_load(os.path.join(path, default.META_FILENAME))
---> 15         super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])
     16 
     17         self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

KeyError: 'package'
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Older versions of spaCy throws "KeyError: 'package'" error when trying to install a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010861/older-versions-of-spacy-throws-keyerror-package-error-when-trying-to-instal)

Comment: I believe this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010861/older-versions-of-spacy-throws-keyerror-package-error-when-trying-to-instal)

Comment: But I JUST NOW installed the newest version possible using 
     conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.0.11

Comment: @running.t No, can confirm that this is a different issue. The sputnik package manager has been deprecated since spaCy v1.7.0, so it looks like the error here happens because there's still some artifact of the old spaCy version available in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python -m spacy download en` ? You need to download the spacy models for the language you want to parse.